# Documentation on how to use Greystripe ads with MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ads

I have found [this binding project](https://github.com/dalexsoto/AlexTouch.Greystripe) which allows the use of `Greystripe` within `Monotouch`

However in the bindings readme it states **"Please go to https://developer.greystripe.com/ for more information on how to use this library"**

It looks like Greystripe has integrated with ValueClick Media and I can't find the documentation for this library anywhere on their new portal.

Does anyone know how to use this binding, or know if it even works with Greystripe anymore? If it doesnt work anymore, is there another way to integrate Greystripe ads into a Monotouch project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most MonoTouch binding projects are not going to have examples. They will normally point you to the documentation for the Objective-C library.

The reason for this is that there is a 1 to 1 mapping of the Objective-C functionality into C#. All your C# code will look almost identical to Objective-C examples. You need to read up on Greystripe's documentation [here](http://support.greystripe.com/ios). The only thing extra you'll need is `using AlexTouch.Greystripe;` at the top in C#.

That being said, we've found Greystripe doesn't pay very well--and now it seems they've merged with some other company it seems less than ideal. We found the best paying ad networks are iAd, Millennial Media, then Admob. There might be some new ones like AdColony that are good, but we haven't tried it yet. If you want some more advice on monetization, hit me up at jonathan dot peppers at gmail.